# Seek table elements with a specific letter combination and remove the last few characters

Tags: r, regex, genetics

I have a table of genes, some of which are duplicated.  I'm not concerned about the duplication.  The duplication comes from a transcript from Ensemble gene database.  When this is reported, it includes the gene XXXX, then adds _ENST00000WWWWWW, this added portion is always 16 characters (where XXXXX is the gene name and WWWWWW are integers).  This shows up as XXXX_ENST00000WWWWWW.  There are simply too many instances to remove these manually.  How can I loop through this, recognize this pattern, and remove those elements?  Example below.

```
       Name              Gene.Name CDS.Mutation AA.Mutation
1       1A                 ASXL3     c.350G>T     p.S117I
2       1A ASXL3_ENST00000269197    c.1229G>T     p.S410I
3       1A              C9orf174      c.95G>A      p.R32Q
4       1A  CLTC_ENST00000269122    c.2128G>C     p.G710R
5       1A                COL4A4     c.274G>A      p.G92R
6       1A                CREBBP    c.4445A>G    p.Y1482C



       Name             Gene.Name CDS.Mutation AA.Mutation
1       1A                 ASXL3     c.350G>T     p.S117I
2       1A                 ASXL3    c.1229G>T     p.S410I
3       1A              C9orf174      c.95G>A      p.R32Q
4       1A                  CLTC    c.2128G>C     p.G710R
5       1A                COL4A4     c.274G>A      p.G92R
6       1A                CREBBP    c.4445A>G    p.Y1482C
```

This is kind of what I pulled together, but I may not know enough to understand this fully. I get a ton of errors on this.

```
raw <- read.xlsx("Mutations.xlsx")
for (i in 1:nrow(raw)){
  if (length(grep("ENST", raw[i,2])) == 1){
    raw[i,2] <- gsub('.{16}$','', raw[i,2])
  }
}
```

Comment: `sub("_.*","",df$Gene.Name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can substitute:

```
 transform(df,Gene.Name=sub("_.*","",Gene.Name))
      Name Gene.Name CDS.Mutation AA.Mutation
    1   1A     ASXL3     c.350G>T     p.S117I
    2   1A     ASXL3    c.1229G>T     p.S410I
    3   1A  C9orf174      c.95G>A      p.R32Q
    4   1A      CLTC    c.2128G>C     p.G710R
    5   1A    COL4A4     c.274G>A      p.G92R
    6   1A    CREBBP    c.4445A>G    p.Y1482C
```

Answer (score 1):

Using positive lookahead `?=` can be one option. Look for characters before `_ENST` and gather those using group.

```
df$Gene.Name <- gsub("(\\w{4,})(?=_ENST).{12}","\\1" ,df$Gene.Name, perl = TRUE)

df
#   Name Gene.Name CDS.Mutation AA.Mutation
# 1   1A     ASXL3     c.350G>T     p.S117I
# 2   1A     ASXL3    c.1229G>T     p.S410I
# 3   1A  C9orf174      c.95G>A      p.R32Q
# 4   1A      CLTC    c.2128G>C     p.G710R
# 5   1A    COL4A4     c.274G>A      p.G92R
# 6   1A    CREBBP    c.4445A>G    p.Y1482C
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text =
"    Name              Gene.Name CDS.Mutation AA.Mutation
1       1A                 ASXL3     c.350G>T     p.S117I
2       1A ASXL3_ENST00000269197    c.1229G>T     p.S410I
3       1A              C9orf174      c.95G>A      p.R32Q
4       1A  CLTC_ENST00000269122    c.2128G>C     p.G710R
5       1A                COL4A4     c.274G>A      p.G92R
6       1A                CREBBP    c.4445A>G    p.Y1482C",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```